# Newtonsoft JSON auto map specific properties

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, automapper

Is there any way to force newtonsoft to swap a type when it encounters a property of that type during serialization/deserialization?

If I have the following:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeNonSerializableType Property { get; set; }
}
```

If during serialization I encounter a `SomeNonSerializableType` I want to use Automapper to map it to a `SomeSerializableType`. I'm assuming I can do this with a contract resolver but not really sure how to implement it. I would then need to do the same in reverse e.g if I encounter a `SomeSerializableType` during deserialization, map it back to `SomeNonSerializableType`.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, you want to to get JSON.Net to use AutoMapper during serialization and deserialization: wouldn't it make more sense to just use AutoMapper to convert the objects before serialization and after deserialization?

Comment: Rather why not create a custom converter and let Automapper takeover? https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html

Comment: @stuartd @sai-gummaluri The reason I was thinking to do it through newtonsoft and not automapper is because I want to do it for any time I encounter those types, not specifically mapping `SomeClass` which lead me to thinking a contract resolver with set mapping profiles for the desired types was the easiest way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [custom generic `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that automatically maps from some model to DTO type during serialization, and maps back during deserialization, like so:

```
public class AutomapperConverter<TModel, TDTO> : JsonConverter
{
    static readonly Lazy<MapperConfiguration> DefaultConfiguration 
        = new Lazy<MapperConfiguration>(() => new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<TModel, TDTO>().ReverseMap()));

    public AutomapperConverter(MapperConfiguration config) => this.config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
    public AutomapperConverter() : this(DefaultConfiguration.Value) { }
    
    readonly MapperConfiguration config;
    
    public override bool CanConvert(Type type) => type == typeof(TModel);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dto = config.CreateMapper().Map<TDTO>(value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dto);
    }
    
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dto = serializer.Deserialize<TDTO>(reader);
        return config.CreateMapper().Map(dto, dto.GetType(), objectType);
    }
}
```

And then add concrete instances to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) like so:

```
// Configure this statically on startup
MapperConfiguration configuration 
    = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
                              {
                                  // Add all your mapping configurations here.
                                  // ReverseMap() ensures you can map from and to the DTO
                                  cfg.CreateMap<SomeNonSerializableType, SomeSerializableType>().ReverseMap();                                
                              });

// Set up settings using the global configuration.
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new AutomapperConverter<SomeNonSerializableType, SomeSerializableType>(configuration) },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someClass, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json, settings);
```

Notes:

- The converter is not intended to handle polymorphism.
- The converter does not support [preservation of object references](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm), but could be extended to do so by using [`JsonSerializer.ReferenceResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_ReferenceResolver.htm) as shown in *[JsonConverter resolve reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48789626/3744182)* or *[Custom object serialization vs PreserveReferencesHandling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53695270/3744182)*.
- The [AutoMapper docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html#where-do-i-configure-automapper) suggest:

  > Configuration should only happen once per AppDomain.

  However the converter will configure a default mapping if none is passed in.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ASTJVb).

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, some generic converter that can handle any model/dto I throw at it via configuration. Really appreciate this in depth answer!

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do something similar yesterday.  Although in my case I only needed to change property name mappings, you can change types with `JsonConverter` like so:

```
public enum UserStatus
{
    NotConfirmed,
    Active,
    Deleted
}

public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

According to the [reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm):

> **JsonConverterAttribute**
> The JsonConverterAttribute specifies which JsonConverter is used to convert an object.
> The attribute can be placed on a class or a member. When placed on a class, the JsonConverter specified by the attribute will be the default way of serializing that class. When the attribute is on a field or property, then the specified JsonConverter will always be used to serialize that value.
> The priority of which JsonConverter is used is member attribute, then class attribute, and finally any converters passed to the JsonSerializer.

According to the [class reference](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor.htm), the type is of [System.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1).

It doesn't sound needed, but possibly also of interest may be the `JsonConstructorAttribute`:

> The JsonConstructorAttribute instructs the JsonSerializer to use a specific constructor when deserializing a class. It can be used to create a class using a parameterized constructor instead of the default constructor, or to pick which specific parameterized constructor to use if there are multiple:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; private set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; private set; }

    public User()
    {
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public User(string userName, bool enabled)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to point me in the right direction, really like the generic approach shown by @dbc but this was useful to get me going with the JsonConverter.

Comment: @ScottKane Yeah dbc nailed it, but I will leave this up since it may help someone else later.